# Having Problems with Jqgrid buildSelect Function

Tags: c#, .net, jqgrid

Using jqGrid ver 5.0.1

I'm having difficulty getting a select list to display using the buildSelect function.  I have tried numerous solutions found on SO, but all seem to have the same problem - the list is populated with "undefined".  Here is my current code:

```
{name: "Status", width: 150,
editable: true, edittype: "select",
editoptions: {
        dataUrl: "Handler3.ashx",
        buildSelect: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var select = '<select>', i, l = data.length, item;
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                item = data[i];
                select += '<option value="' + item.value + '">' + item.name + '</option>';
            }
            return select + '</select>';
        }
    }
```

},

The data returned from the dataUrl (at the alert) is as follows:

```
[{"value":6,"name":"ASSIGNED"},{"value":16,"name":"BLANK"},{"value":14,"name":"CANCELLED"},{"value":3,"name":"COMPLETE"},{"value":15,"name":"HOLD 1ST QTR"},{"value":5,"name":"NEW"},{"value":8,"name":"NOTE"},{"value":7,"name":"ON HOLD"},{"value":4,"name":"PRODUCTION"},{"value":11,"name":"PROPOSED SOLUTION"},{"value":13,"name":"STAGING"},{"value":12,"name":"TESTING"},{"value":9,"name":"WAITING"},{"value":10,"name":"WORKING"}]
```

The code in Handler3.ashx is simply doing a SQL select and returning data:

```
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT LKPID AS value, LKPDESC AS name FROM dbo.PRJLOOKUPS WHERE LKPTYPE = " + "'SCD'" + " AND LKPRSPO <> " + "'INACTIVE'" + " ORDER BY LKPDESC", con);
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                int num = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]));
```

I've also tried calling a SQL stored procedure in the handler to return a formatted string in an Ajax call and setting  the edit options value in load complete.  The string returned is:

```
[{"Column1":"6:ASSIGNED;16:BLANK;14:CANCELLED;3:COMPLETE;15:HOLD 1ST QTR;5:NEW;8:NOTE;7:ON HOLD;4:PRODUCTION;11:PROPOSED SOLUTION;13:STAGING;12:TESTING;9:WAITING;10:WORKING"}]
```

This works somewhat, but the first item in the list looks like "ASSIGNED, and the last looks like WORKING"}]

Can anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong with buildSelect?

Comment: `alert(data)` should not be able to display the correct returned data. It should display just something like "type object". If you see **string** by `alert(data)` then you can fix the problem by usage `data = $.parseJSON(data);` directly at the beginning of `buildSelect`, *before* processing the data.

Comment: @Oleg - thanks a bunch - that solved it.  If you make your comment into an answer, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: You are welcome! The best problem is the solved problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert(data)` should be not able to display the correct returned data. It should display just something like "type object". If you see the string by `alert(data)` then you can fix the problem by usage

```js
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

directly at the beginning of `buildSelect`, *before* processing the data.